# Rails http basic authentication for more than one user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, authentication

So I have a very basic static pages rails app, and I want to create a number of usernames and passwords for people to access these static pages. Naturally, the rails api has the http_basic_atenticate, but how are you supposed to have more than one user?

To be clear, I want to only use http_basic for more than one user. How to go about this?

Eg; user1 has password1, user2 has password2, user3 has password3, and so forth?

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController

http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "user", :password => "password"


  def home
  end

  def content
  end

end
```

Comment: Are you set on creating your own models views and controllers for users passwords forgotten passwords etc..? Most rails users use the Devise gem, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise, as it saves on quite a lot of set up work and does all the leg work for you

Comment: No, I don't want to use a gem. I strictly want to use the http basic method, for a small number of users. I know that devise is the way to go, but in this use case it's too overkill for what I am trying to do.

Is there no way to pass an argument for having multiple users? I feel it's a syntax issue that I can't figure out.

Comment: I think this is a similar problem with a good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536278/ruby-on-rails-how-do-you-do-http-auth-over-multiple-controllers

Comment: That is for authenticating over multiple controllers. What I want to do is just have a list of multiple users and passwords for one controller, not sure how to do that. Something like this I'd imagine, but I can't figure out the syntax.
`http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "user", "user2", :password => "password", "password2"`

Comment: Sorry that's all I got.. only other thing I can think of is doing User.all.each do |user| http_basic_authenticate_with(name: user.name, password: user.password) end

Comment: @mazing if you go to the docs http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html, go to "Advanced Basic example", you'll find how to accomplish what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer. Just pass an array of USERS { .. etc } to a def end block and call it as needed.

```
def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest do |username|
    USERS[username]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution:

```
h = Hash[user1: "Password1", user2: "Password2"]
authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |id, password|
  if h.has_key?(id.to_sym)
    password == h[id.to_sym]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

While the previous answers are certainly 100% correct, I'd like to share an approach which is a little more generic and re-usable (but basically uses the same methods as the previous answers):

**app/controllers/concerns/guest_list_auth.rb**

```
module GuestListAuth
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    cattr_accessor :guest_list
    self.guest_list = :everyone_is_invited

    before_action :perform_guest_list_auth
  end

  class_methods do
    def authenticate_against_guest_list(guest_list)
      self.guest_list = guest_list
    end
  end

  protected
  def perform_guest_list_auth
    return if guest_list == :everyone_is_invited
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Application') do |name, password|
      guest_list.present? &&
        guest_list.has_key?(name.to_sym) &&
        guest_list[name.to_sym] == password.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/static_controller.rb**

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  include GuestListAuth
  authenticate_against_guest_list (
    {
      demo01: '...',
      demo02: '...',
      demo03: '...',
    }
  )

  def home
  end

  # ...
end
```